# Clojure Regex: If string is a URL, return string

Tags: regex, clojure, clojurescript

How can I return a valid URL given a string in Clojure.

```
 (re-matches #"????" "www.example.com"))
 (re-matches #"????" "http://example.com"))
 (re-matches #"????" "http://example.org")) // returns "http://example.org"
 (re-matches #"????" "htasdtp:/something")) // returns nil
```

Comment: Where is the problem? It looks like valid URLs return a value and scrap returns nil. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out the proper URL regex that identifies a URL.

Comment: Use the specs for a valid url. Regex shouldn't be more than 16k bytes.

Answer (score 11):

Validating URL is not simple. Perhaps it's too complex to validate with regexp. Fortunately, there's a library called **Apache Commons**, which contains [UrlValidator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html).

Since Clojure can use Java library, you can use Apache Commons' UrlValidator to validate URL in your program.

First, add dependency in your `project.clj`. Add the following line in your dependency vector.

```
[commons-validator "1.4.1"]
```

And then, you can define a function, `valid-url?` which returns boolean.

```
(import 'org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator)

(defn valid-url? [url-str]
  (let [validator (UrlValidator.)]
    (.isValid validator url-str)))
```

Now, you can do what you want with this function. Or you can modify the above function to return the URL string when it's argument is valid URL.

Comment: How can I import and use it in Clojurescript? I assume it would go under more namespace :require but I'm not sure how the format should be.

Comment: If you need this sort of functionality in clojurescript rather than clojure, use a similar approach, but with javascript libraries rather than java. Remember, while clojure and clojurescript are very similar, they are not identical. In particular, the interop layer is different. Clojure based on java and has an underlying interface to Java objects. Javascript is not an OO language as such and so has slightly different behaviour/restrictions on the interop side. However, you can import javascript libraries, so choose a lib you like which has a url validation function and use that.

Answer (score 2):

Asking how to validate URLs in ClojureScript is basically asking how to do it in Javascript, as ClojureScript regular expressions compile to native JavaScript regular expressions.

This is a page with lots of variants on how to validate URLs using Regular Expressions: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

This is [Diego Pierini's Javascript solution](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294):

```
/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$/i
```

In ClojureScript:

```
(def url-pattern #"(?i)^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$")

(re-matches url-pattern "http://www.google.com")
```